# How to avoid using "Insert copied cells"

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I'm trying to combine the data from a number of worksheets, Source1..N into another sheet, Dest.  There is a sufficiently large number of sheets and rows involved that I'm writing an app in Delphi to do it.  However I've run into a problem with how exactly to do it that can be illustrated by manipulating the worksheets in the Excel gui, and that's how I'm going to try to explain it here, because quoting code will just obscure the issue.

Each of the Source sheets contains a variable number of rows with data in one column and a column next to it, of formulae that uses the data.

When I copy the Source sheets into the Dest one, I want them to end up in vertically separated groups of rows, like so

```
SourceZRow1
SourceZRow2
...
SourceZRowM
...
SourceMRow1
...
SourcePRow1
```

etc.  The order that the pasted Sources appear in Dest is arbitrary.

I thought that the way I'm supposed to avoid the data and formulae in the various pasted Source blocks interfering with one another is to paste each group of Source rows into its own named range of rows.  That seems to work, up to a point, however:

If I want to insert one of the Source blocks, SourceZ, into Dest **above** an already inserted block, SourceM, that seems to work fine if I repeatedly do an Insert to make space above the
the SourceM rows in Dest high enough to receive the SourceZ block, but that is incredibly tedious.  So, I've tried pasting the SourceZ block using

`Right click` `Insert Copied cells` `Shift cells down`

, which moves the SourceM rows down, but NOT the SourceM range-name, so that the SourceM rows are, as it were, pushed down out of their range, so I end up with a vertical block of #VALUE! errors in the formulae column of SourceM.  Of course, this defeats the object of using
named row-ranges in the first place.

So, how should I go about what I'm trying to do in a way which avoids this problem?

This is in Excel 2007, btw.

Update:  I noticed that the original version of this q picked up a VTC because it is not about programming,  But in programming terms, it is quite similar to this q:[Insert Copied Cells as References into a Named Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932842/insert-copied-cells-as-references-into-a-named-range?rq=1), but with "as-references-into-" replaced by "above".